# Will apple accept my app, even though it is more informational?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am wondering if apple will accept my app. It is a fishing app that has a map giving you your current location, and 4 other tabs that contain words and images (bait shops, boat ramps, etc). Lastly, it has a button that takes you to a website that gives you current weather, wind, and wave heights. Will apple consider this too "simple". If so can someone please let me know what to change/do to make it better or acceptable!

Comment: Why not just submit it and see?

Comment: Lol good point, but I want to know whether or not to add things so I dont have to wait as long

Comment: They definitely won't reject it, at least for the reason you specify, they might reject it for another reason but its not clear in your description

Comment: Why not integrate the weather reports into your app too? Should be pretty easy. I have a sample app here: https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon-example

Comment: Wait does anyone know how I could get fishing information (current barometric pressure, wind speed, wave height) on the app? That would be very useful to me!

Comment: These types of apps are referred to and belong in the "Reference" category apps that Apple has on the app store, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note**: Everything I am about to say is just my opinion. I'm not affiliated with Apple's review team, and don't have inside knowledge. These are just my predictions.

From what I understand, your app performs the following functions:

- Map with current location
- Various fishing-related information
- In-app website with fishing-related information

Which means you take advantage of:

- MapKit
- Core Location
- Probably a scroll view
- Images and text
- UIWebViews

Also, your app provides useful information - a huge thing.

In my experience, this type of app should be accepted based on the technologies it uses and the functionality (I assume) it provides.

Comment: Thank you for getting back with me! I hope that you are right!